# C# integrate google webmaster api

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-search-console

I'm busy integrating google webmaster tools into my mvc2 project. I downloaded the google Data API SDK [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list). But i can't figure out how to connect to the api and retrieve information from it. I can't find any assemblies in the SDK i can use in my testproject to connect to the webmaster tools api.

If anybody already tried or has information about this, please share the knowledge. Examples, anything is welcome.

My ultimate plan is to integrate it into a webapplication i'm working so i can communicate with Google Webmaster Tools to get information about keywords, sitemaps and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating the Google Webmaster Tools api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716042/integrating-the-google-webmaster-tools-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it took a while for me to get an answer here i started a new topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716042/integrating-the-google-webmaster-tools-api) This gave me a good solution to work on.