# Integrating the Google Webmaster Tools api

Tags: c#, google-api, google-search-console

I'm researching a project in which I want to integrate the Google Webmaster Tools Api. I already asked this question before in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685791/c-integrate-google-webmaster-api) topic, but i didn't get a response yet.

I've already searched the internet for some good documentation which i already found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/webmastertools/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html) but the documentation doesn't supply a download to the API. I have the Google Data SDK but this doesn't supply an Webmaster Tools API. The SDK was downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) and it states that the Webmaster Tools API should be available

Can anyone tell me if this API is still available and where? And where to find better / more documentation about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the gdata api for your own production u need to build the solution which the SDK installes on your machine as shown here:
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/dotnet_client_lib.html

In the release folder you will find three dll's, one for the extensions, on for the client and one specific for the webmaster tool.

As far as i know there is not a well documented example of the use of the webmaster tools api.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, will try this out and let you know!

Comment: Thanks for the great response! After disabling the Unit Test project which gave me problems, i was able to build the project and retrieve an DLL file to use. Atleast something to work on!

Comment: Works Really great! In just a few lines of code you can get all sites, add sitemaps etcetera. Too bad there isn't more documentation available.

Comment: Hello Rob, I don't know if the solution you found here is still uptodate but could you explain how you did to get these data ? I'm in the same situation a you were...
Here is my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621161/net-get-cookie-for-google-webmaster-tool